# JavaFX - Display background of a disabled Label

Tags: java, css, javafx, label, fxml

With JavaFX, I would like to display a Label with a defined background color (when disabled, my Label's background becomes transparent), and I tried the code below, but that still doesn't work... Have you some tips for me? - Another thread told me to do a `setEditable(false)`, but this approach isn't appropriated in my case.

FXML:

```
<Label styleClass="disable_backgrounded" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="25.0"
       style="-fx-background-color: rgb(252,252,252);-fx-padding: 5px;" text="General" textFill="#aa0000">
           <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0"/>
           </font>
</Label>
```

CSS:

```
.disable_backgrounded:disabled {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(252,252,252);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing this, because the `-fx-opacity` attribute of the `:disabled` controls are set to `0.4` by default.

You can correct your selector as

```
.disabled-label:disabled {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(252,252,252);
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
```

which will show you the disabled `Label` with the needed background color, but **because of the removed opacity, the text color will be the same as on the non-disabled label**.

A work-around can be to set the `-fx-text-fill` attribute directly for the disabled selector by defining the opacity using `rgba`:

```
.disabled-label:disabled {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(252,252,252);
    -fx-opacity: 1;
    -fx-text-fill: rgba(170, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Here is `rgba(170, 0, 0, 0.4)` the RGB version of `#aa0000` with 0.4 alpha defined.

Reference: [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor): RGB Colors section